# Effect of paper type on evaluation of resumes

Tags: reference-request, io-psychology, bias

I heard about an experiment that have shown an effect of the type of paper a resume was printed on, on the evaluation of the resume. If I remember correctly, resumes printed on heavier paper, or attached to heavier writing pads were evaluated as better.

I may have some of the details wrong (for example, it may have been some other job application forms, and not resumes), but hopefully the gist is right.

I tried to look for the reference, but couldn't find it. Does anyone know of a reference presenting such an experiment?

Answer (score 4):

Some findings:

- http://job.sagepub.com/content/21/3/5.full.pdf
- http://www.xavier.edu/appliedhrmresearch/1990-Winter/Henson%20_1_%202.pdf
- http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/j.2164-585X.1979.tb00080.x/abstract (Abstract only)

These articles all seem to deal with paper color (white vs off-white), not quality, and the advent of personal computers and laser printers after this research was completed clearly outdates some of the research questions (e.g. typeset vs typewritten resumés).